# Wait for a process to finish or untill a timeout hits

Tags: python, time, multiprocessing, subprocess, timeout

I am new to multiprocessing in Python. I just came across one problem where I want to have one process that is continously checking whether a file transfer is done. If one minute passes and the transfer is not done I would like to continue in the code.
I found that one way of implementing a timer is to use multiprocessing. I'll try to explain my code:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def isFileTransferDone():
    while(transferOngoing()):
          #File transfer ongoing. 
          #Will return false once transfer is finishedand then I expect process p1 to end 
    print("completed")


def timeout():
    for i in range(1000):
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=isFileTransferDone)
   p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=timeout)
   p1.start()
   p2.start()

   #I am exepcting the program to wait on the below line untill either p1 is finished or until 60 seconds has passed
   if(p1.join() or p2.join(60)):
      if p1.is_alive():
         p1.terminate()
         p2.terminate()
   #I would like my program to continue here
```

I have tried to read about process.join(). I am not sure whether I understand it or not. I am expecting it to wait in the code until that particular process is finished. Perhaps is it something in isFileTransferDone() which is wrong. When whe while-loop is no longer fulfilled I am expecting that process to end?

I would be very thankful for some directions on how I should proceed here :)

Answer (score 0):

First, `join` returns `None`, which is `False`, so your test ...

```py
   if(p1.join() or p2.join(60)):
```

... will always first wait for `p1` to complete and then wait for up to 60 seconds for `p2` to complete. So if `p1` takes longer than 60 seconds to complete you will still be waiting for that completion. If it only took 1 second to complete, you would be waiting an additional 59 seconds for `p2` to complete!

The solution is much simpler:

```py
import multiprocessing


def isFileTransferDone():
    """
    while(transferOngoing()):
        #File transfer ongoing.
        #Will return false once transfer is finishedand then I expect process p1 to end
        ...
    """

    # For demo purposes:
    import time
    time.sleep(2)

    print("completed")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=isFileTransferDone)
    p.start()
    p.join(60) # Wait for up to 60 seconds for task to complete
    if p.is_alive():
        # The process is still running, so kill it:
        p.terminate()
        timeout = True
    else:
        # Process completed normally:
        timeout = False
    # Program continues here after process completes normally or
    # 60 seconds have elapsed and we terminated it.
    # You can test timeout variable
    # to see if timeout occured or not:
    print(timeout)
```

Comment: Thank you Booboo for your great explanation! :) Now it is working and your solution seems much more logical.